# Question about Lang's proof of Jordan-Holder theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is on page 22 of Lang's Algebra book.  Here is the statement and proof of the theorem:

Let $G$ be a group, and let $G= G_1\supset G_2\supset\cdots\supset G_r = \{e\}$ be a normal tower such that $G_{i}/G_{i+1}$ is simple and $G_i \neq G_{i+1}$ for $i = 1,\ldots,r-1$.  Then any other normal tower of $G$ havingthe same properties is equivalent to this one.

Proof: Let $G= H_1\supset H_2\supset\cdots\supset H_s = \{e\}$ be another such normal tower with all quotients being simple groups. Define $G_{ij} = G_{i+1}(H_{j}\cap G_{i})$.  We observe that for each $i$, there exists preciesly one index $j$ such that $G_i/G_{i+1} = G_{ij}/G_{i,j+1}$.  Thus the sequence of non-tribial factors for the original tower, or the refined tower, is the same.

So I'm not quite following this proof.  Why is it true that there is only one index $j$ s.t. "$G_i/G_{i+1} = G_{ij}/G_{i,j+1}$"? and is Lang using that fact to somehow show that the two towers are identical? or is he showing that the $G_{ij}$ refinement is identical to the original tower?  I had some other observation which I think is important and that is if $G_i/G_{i+1}$ is simple then a refinement of the normal tower cannot contain a group between $G_i$ and $G_{i+1}$.  So it seems what Lang is showing is that if there is another normal tower, then you can refine your original normal tower.  I'd really be interested in figuring out this proof because the other proofs I found on it used induction and this one seems pretty slick.

Comment: He uses the Schreier Theorem beforehand!

Comment: What do you mean? I know he uses the same construction for $G_{ij}$ but I thought that was it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a subnormal chain of subgroups (called a normal tower in your post) $$G_{i+1} = G_{is} \unlhd G_{i,s-1} \unlhd \cdots \unlhd G_{i2} \unlhd G_{i1}=G_i.$$ The fact that precisely one of the factors in this series is nontrivial follows from the fact that $G_i/G_{i+1}$ is simple.

Answer (score 2):

You analyzed it correctly. By Schreier's Theorem any two normal towers with simple factors have a equivalent refinement. But since factors are simple their refinements are trivial. Hence all normal towers with simple factors are equivalent.